# Unwarping a set of rectangles to form a square grid in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am trying to map an image which contains these points, drawn as rectangles using top left point and the bottom right points, though I do have the points as quadrilaterals

[image]

I am trying to map the image with the above squares to the squares below:

[image]

I believe that I am supposed to obtain a perspective transform from each quad.  Here is some code that I wrote to try and facilitate this:

```
cv::Mat output = cv::Mat::zeros(outputSize,CV_32F);


    // Uses the size of the quadOutput to
    std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point2f>> quadOutputImage = quadralateralsFromImageOutput(imageToWarp.size().height);

    cv::Mat perspectiveMatrix = cv::Mat(3,3,CV_32F);

    cv::Mat warp = cv::Mat::zeros(outputSize,CV_32F);

    for (int i = 0; i < quadOutputImage.size(); i ++) {

            // get the mapping from the quadtriangles
            perspectiveMatrix = cv::getPerspectiveTransform(quadCentroids[i],quadOutputImage[i]);

            // perform the warp with the current quadtriangles
            cv::warpPerspective(imageToWarp,warp,perspectiveMatrix,output.size());

            // copy roi to output

    }

    return warp;
```

I do this quad by quad and the image does not appear to be correct at all.  It appears that it is slightly skewed.

## Edit

I also tried finding the homography matrix, but I ended up with an odd result.  Here's the code that I wrote

```
    cv::Mat warpedImageGeneration(const cv::Mat& imageToWarp,cv::Size outputSize, std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point2f>> quadCentroids) {        

    // Uses the size of the quadOutput 50 by 50 squares
    std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point2f>> quadOutputImage = quadralateralsFromImageOutput(450);

    // flatten the matrices
    std::vector<cv::Point2f> flattenedQuads = flattenMatrix(quadOutputImage);
    std::vector<cv::Point2f> flattenedCentroids = flattenMatrix(quadCentroids);

    cv::Mat perspectiveMatrix = cv::Mat(3,3,CV_32F);

    cv::Mat warp = cv::Mat::zeros(450,450,CV_32F);

    perspectiveMatrix = cv::findHomography(flattenedCentroids, flattenedQuads);

    cv::warpPerspective(imageToWarp, warp, perspectiveMatrix, warp.size());

    return warp;
 }
```

On an example image, this is the unwarped result I get:

[image]

I think the issue could be that the vertices for the source are out of quadrilateral order i.e top left, top right, bottom left and bottom right.

Comment: If you know the exact coordinates of where each quad from the original image maps to in the warped, try defining **one** perspective transformation matrix that encompasses all of these correspondences together.  Specifically, take a look at all of the corner points for each quad in the source image, determine where they should map in the warped image and define one perspective transformation matrix describing all of these points.  That way, when you provide points from the source image, they should exactly map to the warped points in the warped, and everything else should interpolate cleanly.

Comment: How do I obtain one perspective transformation matrix from all the quads in one image?

Comment: Easy. You already have code that contains a vector of a vector of points for each respective quad for both the input and warped image. You're accessing each vector and specifying this into `getPerspectiveTransform` to get a perspective transformation matrix per quad. Simply specify **one** vector for the input and **one** vector for the warped image that contains **all** of the quad points together, then make a **single** call to `getPerspectiveTransform`. Obviously order is important so make sure that each location of a quad in the input image matches the output location of the warped image.

Comment: Oh ic so instead of doing that loop that I am doing, take all the points that I have in order for both vectors, and stuff it into 2 single vectors, then run the getPerspectiveTransform I was unaware that you could do that, ill try it out!

Comment: Oops.  Looks like I spoke too soon.  If you want to do it like I specified, `getPerspectiveTransform` won't work as it expects 4 points - I thought it did.  You want something else that can handle > 4 points.  Instead of `getPerspectiveTransform`, use `findHomography`:  http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#findhomography .  It basically takes in the same inputs as `getPerspectiveTransform`.  `findHomography` determines the best transformation matrix that maps one set of points from one image to the other image with the least amount of error.

Comment: So!... yes.  Stuff the points into two single vectors, then use `findHomography`.  You can use this in conjunction with `warpPerspective` from the output of `findHomography` and it'll hopefully give you good results.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why the output would be flipped and mirrored like this ? I am checking my points they seem to be correct

Comment: Yeah, that could be because you got the `x` and `y` flipped.  In OpenCV, a `Point` structure contains 2 quantities: `x` and `y`.  `x` is **horizontal** and `y` is **vertical**.  Make sure this ordering is respected before you use `findHomography`.

Comment: Hey it worked that was the case!! thank you!, quick question, do you know the most reliable way to detect vertical and horizontal lines ?  under any lighting condition ?

Comment: That is pretty difficult.  What I would recommend you do is contrast normalize the image so that you can see all of the lines (histogram equalization, gamma correction, etc.), then use the Hough Transform to get the lines out.  BTW, if I wrote an answer, would you mind accepting it? :)

Comment: Yeah for sure! definitely I will be waiting!

Comment: Awesome :) Thanks.  Give me a few minutes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Warping each of the rectangles individually won't give you the best results via `getPerspectiveTransform`.  Instead, if you know the exact coordinates of where each quad from the original image maps to in the warped, try defining **one** perspective transformation matrix that encompasses all of these correspondences together.  Specifically, take a look at all of the corner points for each quad in the source image, determine where they should map in the warped image and define one perspective transformation matrix describing all of these points. That way, when you provide points from the source image, they should exactly map to the warped points in the warped, and everything else should interpolate cleanly.

In terms of implementation, have two `vector` containers where one container contains all of the **source** image points and another `vector` container that contains all of the **warped** image points.  The order matters, so make sure that each location in the source `vector` container corresponds to the same location on the warped `vector` container.

However, you're going to have to change gears and use [`findHomography`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#findhomography) instead.  `findHomography` is the more general case of `getPerspectiveTransform` in that you are determining a transformation matrix that best warps one set of points to another set of points with the least amount of error.  `getPerspectiveTransform` only allows you to specify 4 points.  `findHomography` allows you to specify as many points as you want.

If you want to modify this to your current framework,  you already have code that contains a vector of a vector of points for each respective quad for both the input and warped image. You're accessing each vector and specifying this into `getPerspectiveTransform` to get a perspective transformation matrix per quad. Simply specify one vector for the input and one vector for the warped image that contains all of the quad points together, then make a single call to `findHomography`. Obviously order is important so make sure that each location of a quad in the input image matches the output location of the warped image.

Also, make sure that your coordinate system is correct.  OpenCV's `Point` structures assume that `x` is the **horizontal** coordinate while `y` is the **vertical** coordinate.  As you have placed the edits that I suggested in your original post, I'm going to place them here for completeness and to make the answer self-contained:

```
 cv::Mat warpedImageGeneration(const cv::Mat& imageToWarp,cv::Size outputSize, std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point2f>> quadCentroids) {

    // Uses the size of the quadOutput 50 by 50 squares
    std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point2f>> quadOutputImage = quadralateralsFromImageOutput(450);

    // flatten the matrices
    std::vector<cv::Point2f> flattenedQuads = flattenMatrix(quadOutputImage);
    std::vector<cv::Point2f> flattenedCentroids = flattenMatrix(quadCentroids);

    cv::Mat perspectiveMatrix = cv::Mat(3,3,CV_32F);

    cv::Mat warp = cv::Mat::zeros(450,450,CV_32F);

    perspectiveMatrix = cv::findHomography(flattenedCentroids, flattenedQuads);

    cv::warpPerspective(imageToWarp, warp, perspectiveMatrix, warp.size());

    return warp;
 }
```